# mvn compile - [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: java, maven

I am running `mvn compile` from the command line and am getting this:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:12 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-24T10:19:32+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project spring-boot-sam
ple-atmosphere: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

I've seen this answer but it's for Eclipse.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set JDK instead of JRE as environment (download it if necessary)

JDK=JRE+Codingstuff (including a compiler)

Comment: That was the issue.

Answer (score 3):

you need to update environment variable( give JDK path in ENV variable )
 here [link](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/) how to set up